Finding training MSE from cv.glmnet R package
I've been trying to find the MSE for the training dataset when using the cv.glmnet function from the glmnet package in R.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
The best I've come up with is below but I'm not sure if it's correct
set.seed(34064064)
library(ISLR2)
Library(glmnet)

x<- matrix.model(Salary~.,data=Hitters)[,-1]
y<- Hitters$Salary

cv<-cv.glmnet(x,y,lambda=exp(seq(-2, 4, length.out = 30)),k=10,alpha=1,standardize = TRUE,type.measure = "mse")

best.lambda <- cv$lambda.min

fit <- glmnet(x, y, lambda=best.lambda, alpha=0, standardize=TRUE)

y.pred <- predict(fit, newx=x)

training.mse <- mean((y - y.pred)^2)

print(training.mse)


You can use the glmnet::assess.glmnet function, which provides summary performance measures for the glmnet model.
library(ISLR2)
library(glmnet)

Hitters <- na.omit(Hitters)
x <- model.matrix(Salary~., data=Hitters)[,-1]
y <- Hitters$Salary

cv <- cv.glmnet(x,y, lambda=exp(seq(-2, 4, length.out = 30)), k=10, 
                alpha=1, standardize = TRUE, type.measure = "mse")

best.lambda <- cv$lambda.min
fit <- glmnet(x, y, lambda=best.lambda, alpha=1, standardize=TRUE)

# The method based on "predict"
y.pred <- predict(fit, newx=x)
training.mse <- mean((y - y.pred)^2)
print(training.mse)

[1] 94310.44

# The method based on "assess.glmnet"    
perf <- assess.glmnet(fit, newx=x, newy=y)
print(perf$mse)

      s0 
94310.44
attr(,"measure")
[1] "Mean-Squared Error"


Thanks for getting back to me, just was wondering if removing column 19 in the as.matrix(Hitters[,-19]) is the same as matrix.model(Salary~.,data=Hitters), and as to why you didn't remove the intercept in your answer, I've always been confused over the intercept.

@SCZZI In glmnet, there is the argument intercept: Should intercept(s) be fitted (default = TRUE) or set to zero (FALSE)? There is no need to add a column of ones to the x matrix.

@SCZZI I did not realize that there is a factor variable (NewLeague) in the Hitters dataset. Therefore, I made a mistake when I used as.matrix because the x matrix was transformed into a matrix of strings. Your solution with model.matrix is correct because it properly handles the factor variable. I have modified my post and apologize for the error.
